# How to get last 1 mb data of a text file using java code?

Tags: java

I have 500 mb log file in server ( .txt file) . My requirement is I want only the last 1 mb data only . As all of us know it will cause a problem if I read entire file using java code and It may cause the usability issue of the application . I have no idea how to get the last one MB data and not yet started the coding . Any one can please give me suggestion ?

Thanks in Advance,

Raj

Comment: If you are using some logging framework then use *`MaxFileSize`* option of configuration. 500MB log file *too big*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246744

Comment: @HarryJoy it may be too big if you are worried about the ability to use the file.  For some projects multi GB logs files don't have to be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your problem you just need to use a random access file and to place the cursor using the seek() method  to the end minus 1mb ...
Please read the java.io.RandomAccessFile javadoc especially the seek() comments...

HTH
Jerome

Comment: Hope it will solve my problem .. Start reading the document .. Thansk for the help

Answer (score 1):

> I have 500 mb log file in server ( .txt file) . My requirement is I want only the last 1 mb data only .

You can skip tot he last 1 MB and read that.  You might get an incomplete line however.

> As all of us know it will cause a problem if I read entire file using java code and It may cause the usability issue of the application .

Only if you code it rather poorly.  There is no good read it would do this.  However, there is no good read to read 500 MB if you know you only need the last 1 MB.

> I have no idea how to get the last one MB data and not yet started the coding . Any one can please give me suggestion ?

Start coding, read the documentation, esp the skip function.